# Error starting solr with plugin which uses spark libraries

Tags: java, solr, apache-spark, jetty, akka

I am trying to start solr with a custom plugin which uses spark library. I am trying to initialize sparkcontext in local mode. I have made a fat jar for this plugin using maven shade and put it in the lib directory. **While starting solr it is not able to initialize sparkcontext.** It says class not found exception for AkkaRpcEnvFactory. Can anyone please help.

**It gives the following error:**

```
3870 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext  – Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory
```

**Here is the detailed error**

```
java -jar start.jar
0    [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server  – jetty-8.1.10.v20130312
27   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider  – Deployment monitor /home/rahul/solr-4.7.2/example/contexts at interval 0
40   [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager  – Deployable added: /home/rahul/solr-4.7.2/example/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml
1095 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor  – NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
1155 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  – SolrDispatchFilter.init()
1189 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – JNDI not configured for solr (NoInitialContextEx)
1190 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – solr home defaulted to 'solr/' (could not find system property or JNDI)
1190 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
1280 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSolr  – Loading container configuration from /home/rahul/solr-4.7.2/example/solr/solr.xml
1458 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Config-defined core root directory: /home/rahul/solr-4.7.2/example/solr
1465 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – New CoreContainer 602710225
...............

3870 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext  – Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.getRpcEnvFactory(RpcEnv.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at com.snapdeal.search.spark.SparkLoadModel.loadModel(SparkLoadModel.java:11)
    at com.snapdeal.search.valuesource.parser.RankingModelValueSourceParser.init(RankingModelValueSourceParser.java:29)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.createInitInstance(SolrCore.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2191)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2185)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initPlugins(SolrCore.java:2218)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initValueSourceParsers(SolrCore.java:2130)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:765)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:630)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:562)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:597)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:258)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:250)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
3880 [coreLoadExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.spark.SparkContext  – Successfully stopped SparkContext
```